# c# and Java math.exp

Tags: c#, java

in Visual C#

```
double arena = 2.0;    
double arcilla = 4.0;

double arena2 = arena * arena;
double arcilla2 = arcilla * arcilla;

double ac = Math.Exp(-4.396 - 0.0715 * arcilla - 0.000488 * arena2 - 0.00004285 * arena2 * arcilla);
```

`ac = 0.00923608116161322`

in eclipse

```
double arena = 2.0;    
double arcilla = 4.0;

double arena2 = arena * arena;
double arcilla2 = arcilla * arcilla;

double ac = Math.Exp(-4.396 - 0.0715 * arcilla - 0.000488 * arena2 - 0.00004285 * arena2 * arcilla);
```

`ac =  0.32334282156236527`

Why are the results different???

Comment: How are you using C# in Eclipse? (Note that you haven't given valid Java in the second part of the question, which I suspect you meant to.)

Comment: I'm having a visual basic program to java and I am programming in eclipse did the same formulas but the results are different to be that Ac is the result thanks

Comment: Well you haven't posted either Java *or* VB yet...

Comment: @MartinDiegoPinedoDavila ok this is very confusing. Why do you mention `VB` and post `C#` code? and then why do you mention java and again post `C#` code, saying "in eclipse"?

Comment: mathematica gives 0.00923608 for the same code.  So "C#" (quoted for obvious reasons) is the correct answer.

Comment: @FelixCastor that confirms my suspicions that java doesn't know how to multiply. Nice.

Comment: We could guess what the actual problem is all night.  Personally, I think there's a multiplication of ~35 he's not telling us about...

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same values in the `Java` program as you are in the `C#` program? Getting `0.009236081161613216` as a result from `Java`.

Answer (score 3):

This is just not true. Both give basically the same result.

Eclipse:
0.009236081161613216

Visual Studio:
0.00923608116161322

I just changed Math.Exp to Math.exp to run your code in Eclipse.